# Couldn't share G+ plus URL

Tags: html, google-plus, share

I'm running C# with angularJS. I used Google sharing button last time. It works. But currently I had tried again, it doesn't work anymore. It only works on other website but not from my site.

**Controller**

```
$scope.getShareGoogleURL = function (p) {
    var url = BASE_URL + "/property/" + p.property_id;
    return encodeURIComponent(url);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a target="_blank" href="javascript:void(window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url={{ getShareGoogleURL(p) }}', 'Share to Google+','width=600,height=460,menubar=no,location=no,status=no'));">
    <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
</a>
```

When I clicked the G+ button, it pops up a window, and I login google account. It shows

> That link isn't invalid, Check it & try again.

Example Link: https://lskserver.azurewebsites.net/properties/newSale

Comment: Is it a URL that is public on the internet?

Comment: @abraham https://lskserver.azurewebsites.net/properties/newSale ... G share button on the list.